# Multiplying, dividing numbers with a specific format

Tags: java, linked-list, operation

Today, I have a question about multiplying, dividing numbers with a specific format. The format is like this: I will make the number into a linked list, and do the operation with this linked list. For example, if I want to multiply 1234567 and 7890123, I will make these two numbers into linked list by cutting the numbers into 3 digits at one time, like 1,234,567 and 7,890,123. Then, I will put one chunk at one node(1, 234, 567 are three chunks, and they all go into different nodes) for every numbers. Now, the problem is, I have to multiply, divide, and get the quotient and remnant of the operation between the two numbers without changing them back to the real 'numbers'. The operation must be done with the form of linked list. So, for the multiplying, I've thought 'let's multiply the numbers in each node first, and put the zeros in the back to adjust the cipher, then add them all to finish the operation. for example, if I want to multiply 1,234 and 5,678, I will do (234*678 + (1*678)000 + (5*234)000 + (1*5)000,000). But, I can't be certain this method is right, And I can't imagine about the dividing and getting the quotient and remnant part. So, please help..!

Comment: Search on the web for long division. This was used back in the pencil and paper days.

Comment: @NomadMaker Thanks for the comment! I've searched for the long division, and only find out about the polynomial long division and int -> double long division. So, what do I have to find out about, exactly? And I'm not sure about the multiply either, so please comment on that as well, please..!!

Comment: Multiply is done just as you do it by hand, but in base 1000.